# Hibernate String Primary Key with Annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, primary-key

I am trying to create a Privilege class with Annotations whose Primary Key is a String. I will assign them manually while inserting. Therefore no need for hibernate to generate a value for it. I'm trying to do something like that:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "assigned")
@Column(name = "ROLE_NAME", nullable = false)
private String roleName;
```

But it throws that exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown Id.generator: assigned
```

How can I configure a `String` primary key with annotations?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Since the `roleName` is not auto-generated, you should simply not annotate it with `@GeneratedValue`:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ROLE_NAME", nullable = false)
private String roleName;
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me and I can see that the field is the PrimaryKey of the table.

Answer (score 6):

```
@Id
@Column(name = "USER_ID",unique=true,columnDefinition="VARCHAR(64)")
private String userId;
```

This worked for me by representing the columnDefinition type with column annotation during the save or update.

Comment: this also helped with table's auto-creation in the schema, but only when setting length to 64, it would not work when set on 255. do you have any info on why is 64 better than 255?

Answer (score 4):

Just use the `@Id` annotation which lets you define which property is the identifier of your entity. You don't need to use the `@GeneratedValue` annotation because I don't think you want hibernate to generate this property for you.

Even in the XML configuration based approach its an optional tag and can be skipped.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I thought `@GeneratedValue` is required but actually it is not :)

Answer (score 1):

you can enter this way, suppose position is primary key of that Salary entity,

```
@Id
@Column (name = "POSITION", nullable = false)
private String position;
```

then, it will work